# ArrayAdapter: ListView change getView arguement value of position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am developing in Android 4.4 and I am relatively new to android development.

Here is my custom array adapter to use in a listView:

```
class teamsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
String[] teamName;
String[] teamRecord;
int teamLogo[];

teamsAdapter(Context c, String[] teamName, int[] teamLogo,
        String[] teamRecord) {
    super(c, R.layout.activity_teams, R.id.teamList, teamName);
    this.context = c;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamLogo = teamLogo;
    this.teamRecord = teamRecord;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    int teamLeft = position;        // 1
    int teamRight = position + 1;   // 2

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elements_teams, parent, false);

    TextView teamNameLeft = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamNameLeft);
    ImageView teamLogoLeft = (ImageView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.teamLogoLeft);
    TextView teamRecordLeft = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.teamRecordLeft);

    TextView teamNameRight = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.teamNameRight);
    ImageView teamLogoRight = (ImageView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.teamLogoRight);
    TextView teamRecordRight = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.teamRecordRight);

    teamNameLeft.setText(teamName[teamLeft]);
    teamLogoLeft.setImageResource(teamLogo[teamLeft]);
    teamRecordLeft.setText(teamRecord[teamLeft]);

    teamNameRight.setText(teamName[teamRight]);
    teamLogoRight.setImageResource(teamLogo[teamRight]);
    teamRecordRight.setText(teamRecord[teamRight]);

    return row;

}

}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have 3 static arrays (2 strings and one int) which all three contain 16 elements.

For each row in the listView, I want to display the first two elements. So for example:

```
ROW 1: teamName[1] teamLogo[1] teamRecord[1] and teamName[2] teamLogo[2] teamRecord[2]
ROW 2: teamName[3] teamLogo[3] teamRecord[3] and teamName[4] teamLogo[4] teamRecord[4]
```

and so on...

Is there a way that I can re-assign the value of `position` after each iteration? So after the first iteration, `position = position + 2` ?

I hope that this made sense. Thank you so much in advance for any help you can offer. Also, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

-Patrick

Comment: *Is there a way that I can re-assign the value of position after each iteration?* - no there isn't, the position parameter is provided by the adapter. Anyway, you wouldn't want to do that, instead simply map the received position to the actual indexes: `int realPos = position * 2;`. You can then use `realPos` and `realPos + 1` directly in the arrays.

Comment: I think that you have to reconsider the way that you pass the data into the adapter

Comment: I tried that originally @Luksprog, however once 'position > 8' i receive an arrayOutOfBounds error. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: If you pass `teamName` in the super constructor then the adapter will think you have 16 rows(but you want 8 judging that you use 2 array items per row, right?). Instead also override `getCount()` to return `teamName.length / 2` (or 8 directly).

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you! I did something similar to your suggestion and it worked. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not do write this logic in getView inside adapter. Process the data first,make it ready for display and the pass the array to your adapter like,

```
String arrayToAdapter [] = new String[8] ;

    for(int i = 0,j=0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++,j++){

      arrayToAdapter[j] = arr1[i]+ " " + arr2[i] + " " +arr3[i] +" and "+arr1[i+1]+ " " + arr2[i+1] + " " +arr3[i+1]

    i+=2 ;


    }
```

Then pass arrayToAdapter to your list adapter